# call a function from view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to know how I can call a controller function from view,here is the code,there a some few examples but I couldn't understand,

**controller**

```
<?php

class Site2 extends CI_Controller{

 public function account_details($id){
        $this->load->model('bank_account_model');
        $data['ac_results'] = $this->bank_account_model->getAccount();
        $this->load->view('view_header');
        $data['results'] = $this->get_company_model->get_All();
        $this->load->view('view_nav',$data);
        $this->load->view('bank_account_detais.php');
        $this->load->view('view_footer');
    }

}
```

from the view I need to call acccount_detail function with parameters,

Comment: Put it in a helper instead of a controller and make sure the controller loading the view loads the helper http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/helpers.html

Comment: Have you thought about using hmvc you can call functions using `echo modules::run` etc

Answer (score 0):

It is really best to NOT call a function from a view, but if you insist, you have several options.

1) You can create a helper (as suggested by xd6_), then load the helper before invoking the view(s).

2) You can put the function in the model and pass the model to the view--similar to how you sent `$data` to the `view_nav` view.

3) You can call the function before invoking the view and pass the result to the view, again similar to how you send `$data`.

4) You can add the function NOT as a member of you controller, but still defined in the the same file as your controller. (I'm not claiming this is a good practice, but it can be done.)